# Possible to validate fields from larger zod schema in sub schema

Tags: javascript, typescript, schema, zod

Using `zod`, I'm looking to validate two fields using `refine` that are part of a larger schema. Here's my main schema:

```
const mainSchema = z.object({ 
  id: z.string(),
  email: z.string(),
  phone: z.number(),
  firstName: z.string(),
  lastName: z.string(),
  param1: z.optional(z.string()),
  param2: z.optional(z.string()),
})
```

My main schema grows in size and will continue to do so over time.

I realize I can use `.refine` to check if both `param1` and `param2` are not `undefined` in the main schema like this:

```
const mainSchema = z.object({ 
  ...otherProps,
  param1: z.optional(z.string()),
  param2: z.optional(z.string()),
}).refine(({ param1, param2 }) => { 
   if (param1 == undefined && param2 == undefined)
}, 
{message: "param1 or param2 must be defined"})
```

That seems a bit messy to me considering I could have multiple refine statements I need to run in the main schema.

**Is there a way to separate this out into it's own schema without defining a new property and wrapping `param1` and `param2` in it's own object?**

Ideally I'd look for something like this:

```
const subSchema = z
  .object({
    param1: z.optional(z.string()),
    param2: z.optional(z.string())
  })
  .refine(
    ({ param1, param2 }) => {
      if (param1 == undefined && param2 == undefined) {
         return false
      }
    },
    { message: 'param1 or param2 must be defined' }
  )
```

then inject into the main schema:

```
const mainSchema = z.object({ 
  id: z.string(),
  email: z.string(),
  phone: z.number(),
  firstName: z.string(),
  lastName: z.string(),
  ...subSchema
})
```

Comment: Did you try `z.merge`?

Comment: That looked promising but I got this error:

```Argument of type 'ZodEffects<ZodObject<{ param1: ZodOptional<ZodString>; param2: ZodOptional<ZodString>; }, "strip", ZodTypeAny, { ...; }, { ...; }>, { ...; }, { ...; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyZodObject'.```

I tried `.merge` both ways; with the `mainSchema` and `subSchema` as params

Comment: Did you try `mainSchema.and(z.object({ param1: z.any() }))`?

Comment: Or `ms.pick(['param1']).required()`?